# Azure Batch Linked Service Not Found in ADF Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-batch

I am trying to deploy an ADF pipeline using an ARM template. Below is the portion of the code for by azure batch linked service:

```
{
      "type": "linkedservice",
      "name": "AzureBatchLS",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('dataFactoryName')]"
      ],
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-01",
      "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBatch",
        "typeProperties": {
          "accountName": "<acct name>.eastus2",
          "accessKey": <access key>,
          "poolName": "<pool name>",
          "linkedServiceName": "Dev-LinkedService"
        }
      }
    }
```

However, each time during deployment, I get the following error message:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:22:08 PM - Resource Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/linkedservice '<adf name>/AzureBatch' failed with message '{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" 
content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
\r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 
2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div 
id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>\r\n  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily 
unavailable.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  }
}'
At C:\Users\tsolanki\Desktop\OBFoundationCloudPoC\Solution\HCLS-OBF-ARM-Templates\DataTransfer_v0.1\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:110 char:5
+     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).Base ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I have checked multiple time to make sure the naming is correct and the resource is online and in that subscription. Has anyone seen this error before? I can't seem to find any solution on the web for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `type` to `"linkedservices"`

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. Anyways, thank you! I can imagine myself stuck on this for hours just because of a typo. They really should show better error messages IMO.